# how to disable/unbind jquery live() if it is already exist in the page?

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where Jquery Live() function need to be disable/unbind if it is already exist on the page.

Let's say I've two components, each component is one jsp and both have same javascript function.

JS:

```
(function(a) {
    a(function() {
    a(".show").live(
    "click", function(){

 }); })(jQuery);
```

If I drag and drop first component it is working fine but when I drop second component...existing component functionality is not working since it has duplicate JS and selectors..

Is there a way that I can unbind or disable jquery live()  for the second component when I drag and drop.

Appreciate your help...

Comment: Why are you assigning `jQuery` to `a`?

Comment: What are you dragging and dropping? You haven't provided any code that shows dragging and dropping.

Comment: @benastan It's a way to provide an abbreviation, if you're already using `$` for something else.

Comment: I get that, but in the context of StackOverflow, it would maintain clarity if he just used $ of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

To remove a binding that was created using `.live()`, use `.die()`:

```
$(".show").die("click");
```

If you bound the event to a named function, you could remove just that one handler by passing the function in as the second argument to `.die()`. But since you're binding to an anonymous function, you can't provide that as the argument, so all click handlers bound using `.live()` will be removed.

See http://api.jquery.com/die/ for more information. Also, `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9. You should convert your code to use `.on()`.

It's possible you don't need to do this in the first place, though. Why are you calling `.live()` multiple times? You only need to call it once, and it will apply to all elements matching the selector, even if they're added later. That's the reason to use `.live()` or `.on()`, rather than `.bind()`.

Comment: Barmar: I'm using a(window).bind("load", function() {
  })   ...inside that custom function to call it onload...how I can call die...if the function is arleady esit